# help with regex, variable is not expanding within a pattern

Tags: php, regex

Code:

```
$source = file_get_contents('http://php.about.com/od/learnphp/qt/hello_world.htm');
$test_var = "hello world";
$pattern = "|<h[^>]+>($test_var)</[^>]+>|i";
echo $pattern;

$test = preg_match_all($pattern,$soure,$matches);
```

Output:

```
|]+>(  )]+>|i
ArrayArrayArray ( [0] => Array ( ) [1] => Array ( ) )
```

Comment: It works nice for me. But what is the question ?

Comment: If I'm correct in assuming you're trying to capture the contents of HTML header tags, then you're missing the last `h`, `$pattern = "|<h[^>]+>(" . $test_var . ")</h[^>]+>|i`

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
// match all headings
$pattern = "|<h[^>]+>([^>]+)<\/h[^>]+>|i";

// match heading containing "hello world"
$test_var = "hello world";
$pattern = "|<h[^>]+>(" . $test_var . ")</h[^>]+>|i";
```

Example:

```
php > $source = file_get_contents('http://php.about.com/od/learnphp/qt/hello_world.htm');
php > $pattern = "|<h[^>]+>([^>]+)<\/h[^>]+>|i";
php > preg_match_all($pattern, "<h1>hello world</h1>", $matches);
```

Although from what I can discern, there shouldn't be an issue with the code you have posted.
What exactly is the question/issue?

Comment: $pattern = "|<h[^>]+>(" . $test_var . ")</[^>]+>|i";;
echo $pattern;

$test = preg_match_all($pattern,$soure,$matches);
$print_r($matches);

now varible is expanding but i am get a empty array values

Comment: Please post what is in `$source`

Comment: You're missing the last `h` `$pattern = "|<h[^>]+>(" . $test_var . ")</h[^>]+>|i`

Comment: $source  = "Every language has it... the basic "Hello, World!" script. It is a simple script that only displays the words "Hello, World!". Over the years this has become the traditional phrase to use when writing your first program. According to wikipedia, it's mainstream usage spawned from an internal memorandum in 1974 that became incorporated into the book The C Programming Language. It's actual first known usage was in Kernighan's 1972 A Tutorial Introduction to the Language B. From this it has grown into somewhat of a tradition in the programming world."

Comment: Your pattern doesn't match that anything in that text. What are you trying to pull out?

Comment: the problem issue empty arrays

Comment: That's because your pattern is wrong. What do you want to be in the array?

Comment: So you want to match all html header tags <h1> etc... but there are no header tags in source

Comment: $source = file_get_contents('http://php.about.com/od/learnphp/qt/hello_world.htm');